# How to use a shortcut to restart the new MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, restart, eject

> [Control–Command–Media Eject: Quit all apps, then restart your Mac. If any open documents have unsaved changes, you will be asked whether you want to save them.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

But the new MacBook Pro doesn't have the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own key commands in system prefs
<sub>This will be probably a lot harder to find in Ventura:\</sub>

[image]

[image]

There's one slight quirk, though with both Shutdown… & Restart…

As soon as you add a custom key command to either of them, an alternative command pops up underneath, without the ellipsis. You can't add a key command to these non ellipsis versions.

Comment: Upvoted, I'm curious how do you sync these shortcuts between Macs? They can take a long time to configure.

Comment: I've never needed to. All my Macs are migrations of one prime Mac back in 2000. So my main Mac is always a direct line of sight back to that one. My others are newer forks from that main Mac. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461918/how-to-copy-app-shortcuts-to-another-user-or-mac

Comment: How did you do the migration or forking? Did you use [this method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461985/424683)?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/HT204350 Although with the older Mac Pros with multiple internal drives, I would just clone the boot drive & put it in the new Mac. Can't do that any more.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), the following rule maps <kbd>left_command</kbd>+<kbd>right_command</kbd>+<kbd>escape</kbd> to restart macOS:

```json
{
  "description": "Restart macOS",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "from": {
        "key_code": "escape",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_command", "right_command"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "key_code": "eject",
          "modifiers": ["left_control", "left_command"]
        }
      ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Thinkr Which shortcut?

Comment: @Thinkr "* Does not apply to the Touch ID sensor." The new MBP doesn't have a power button though.

Comment: Or, same as your other question you just added a Karabiner answer to - you can set your own key commands in system prefs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/My4cZ.png

Comment: @Thinkr I tried "Control–Command–Touch ID", it just locks the screen.

Comment: @Thinkr I held "Control-Touch ID" for three seconds, but it still locked the screen.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance, I was mistaken.

Comment: @Thinkr It's all right, thanks for reaching out.